# Symantec Backup Exec and connecting to IPC shares?

Tags: backup, backupexec, ipc

I am hoping to be able to have Symantec Backup Exec (2010) connect to some Windows machines via their IPC shares for backup.

It seems to work for a couple machines I tried, but several others it's not.

For example, I was able to add a user defined selection (when creating a job) and type \machinename\c$

I was then able to click on that in the user defined selections and it showed the contents of the C drive.

However, for a few other machines I tried, it will either say 'communications error'.  I think I was also getting a timeout error message.  It will also say "Query failed" in the right window pane where the files should be displayed.   Backup exec is set up to use a domain administrator account, and logged in as that user on the backup exec machine I can mount that ipc share with no issue by typing \machinename\c$

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the remote agent required for connecting to User Defined shares? I never remember whether it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you query those machines directly from another windows box?  if not, then the server service might be stopped, firewall might be blocking it etc...

FWIW, there is a client agent for BEW that can be installed on the client for taking care of these types of issues.

Comment: Yes, I can also mount the machines from another windows box.